# What part is this?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I need some help identify this part number or name. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is part of either:

[TOOL WHEEL](https://brickset.com/parts/design-6246) (1999 - 2012)

[image]

or

[TOOL WHEEL](https://brickset.com/parts/design-11402) (2007 - 2019)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like *[Part #6246d - Minifigure, Utensil Tool Box Wrench - 6-Rib Handle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6246d&idColor=0#T=C&C=0)*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This piece looks to be an older Wrench piece:
[Minifigure, Utensil Tool Box Wrench - 6-Rib Handle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6246d&idColor=0#T=C&C=0). 
Picture shows the part in, what seems to be, in a shade of brown color. Unfortunately this piece doesn't come from LEGO in similar color.

There's a newer piece, with less ribs:
[Minifigure, Utensil Tool Box Wrench - 3-Rib Handle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11402i#T=C).
This part isn't produced by LEGO in any shades of brown too. At least for the moment of this answer. However it comes in a few other colors compared with an older 6-rib piece.

Comment: After trying to [white balance the image a bit](https://i.imgur.com/vo7cKWM.png), I think that piece might actually be dark grey.